# Iterating arraylist until find an specific character and stop the iteration

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, iterator

I'm trying to iterate an arraylist and then make it stop when it finds a character, in this case, a comma. This is what I have:

This is the arraylist:

```
List<String> collection = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"I", "f", " ", "y", "o", "u", " ", "g", "e", "t", " ", "a", " ", "t", "e", "x", "t", " ", "m", "e", "s", "s", "a", "g", "e", " ", "f", "r", "o", "m", " ", "a", "n", " ", "e", "m", "a", "i", "l", " ", "a", "d", "d", "r", "e", "s", "s", " ", "o", "r", " ", "n", "u", "m", "b", "e", "r", " ", "y", "o", "u", " ", "d", "o", "n", "'", "t", " ", "r", "e", "c", "o", "g", "n", "i", "z", "e", ",", " ", "i", "t", "'", "s", " ", "p", "r", "o", "b", "a", "b", "l", "y", " ", "b", "e", "s", "t", " ", "t", "o", " ", "i", "g", "n", "o", "r", "e", " ", "i", "t"});
```

And this is the method I'm using on main: showUntil();

```
private static void showUntil() {

    for(String g : collection){
        if(g.equals(",")){
            System.out.println(g);
        }

    }
}
```

I'm using java for this exercise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you stop a loop from running in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006972/how-do-you-stop-a-loop-from-running-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `indexOf` function and iterate till that index. This is one approach

```
List<String> collection = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"I", "f", " ", "y", "o", "u", " ", "g", "e", "t", " ", "a", " ", "t", "e", "x", "t", " ", "m", "e", "s", "s", "a", "g", "e", " ", "f", "r", "o", "m", " ", "a", "n", " ", "e", "m", "a", "i", "l", " ", "a", "d", "d", "r", "e", "s", "s", " ", "o", "r", " ", "n", "u", "m", "b", "e", "r", " ", "y", "o", "u", " ", "d", "o", "n", "'", "t", " ", "r", "e", "c", "o", "g", "n", "i", "z", "e", ",", " ", "i", "t", "'", "s", " ", "p", "r", "o", "b", "a", "b", "l", "y", " ", "b", "e", "s", "t", " ", "t", "o", " ", "i", "g", "n", "o", "r", "e", " ", "i", "t"});
         
for(String chr : collection.subList(0, collection.indexOf(","))) {
    System.out.println(chr);
}
```

If you want to correct the code you have written, you need to break from the loop if you find a match like below

```
for(String g : collection) {
    if(g.equals(",")) {
        System.out.println(g);
        break; //exit the loop if comma is found!
    }
}
```

Comment: And the first one did the trick, thank you!

Comment: Perofrmance-wise it's a horrible choice. It traverses the list twice when one traversal would suffice and creates an unnecessary throwaway object. You need to understand what each library method does before you call them.